# Google Assistant custom action programming - speak few words of a constant prompt speech slower

Tags: actions-on-google, voice, actions-builder, vui

I am building a custom action for Google Assistant on the web view of https://console.actions.google.com/

One of the responses is a long prompt sentence consisting of something like:

- Easy to understand "please send a postal letter to"

Then

- Hard to understand address (with letters and numbers in UK postcode, like "XX12 1XX", and an ambiguously sounding street name)

Then

- Easy to understand "and please ... enquiry ..."

It's all defined in the yaml of the welcome prompt of the given scene:

```yaml
    candidates:
      - first_simple:
        variants:
          - speech: |-
              Please ... where the address is ... ... and please ... enquiry ...
```

Is there a way to fine tune this "speech"? Or is there an alternative to make Google assistant say this constant text with a slower pace in the middle part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [SSML](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/ssml) to send back the reply instead of text, which is converted using a simpler text-to-speech model.

This SSML can include a [prosody tag with a rate](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/ssml#prosody) attribute for part of what you send so it speaks that part slower.

So it might look something like

```yaml
    candidates:
      - first_simple:
        variants:
          - speech: |-
              <speak>Please ... where the address is <prosody rate="30%"> ... ...</prosody> and please ... enquiry ...</speak>
```

You may also wish to look at the [say-as tag](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/ssml#say%E2%80%91as) to spell out the characters in the address. That specific part in SSML might look something like

```
   <say-as interpret-as="characters">XX12 1XX</say-as> somewhere street
```